# Change the base of the numeration

Tags: page-numbering

In a document, is it possible to change the base in which the numeration is written? The default numeration is decimal, but I would like to use an octal or hexadecimal numeration for instance.

Also, when I use a document class 'book' or 'report', how can I set a negative numeration before the main text? What I mean by this is that instead of small latin numeration (i, ii, iii, iv, ...) I would like the pages to decrease with a negative sign in front. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each counter is usually printed with a macro named `\thecounter` where `counter` is the counter name, i.e. the page number is stored in the `page` counter and the `\thepage` macro is used to typeset it. The chapters use the `chapter` counter etc. If you want to change the base of the displayed number simple redefine this macro(s) using `\renewcommand`. The `pgf` package provides macros to display numbers in octal and hexadecimal.

If you want to start the page numbers with a negative or any other number simply set the `page` counter to this number using `\setcounter{page}{<number>}`. This should be best done in the preamble.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [fmtcount](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) package and tinker with the `page` counter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\addtocounter{page}{-4}

\blinddocument

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\hexadecimal{page}}

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is now the [`moreenum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moreenum) package that allows you to do binary, octal and hexadecimal enumeration. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\enumHex*,start=8]
\item one
\item two
\item three
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

(`moreenum` automatically loads `enumitem` so I used `enumitem`'s `start` option to illustrate that this really is hex numbering, rather than having a list of >9 items...)

Comment: I've noticed that the original question was not about `enumerate` environments. But I will leave the answer here, since this shows up when searching for `enumeration`

Answer (score 2):

As fmtcount does not work together with lastpage or totpages I had to find another solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,ngerman]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext,pgffor}
\input binhex

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{0x\hex{\value{page}}}

\foreach \x in {0,...,4} {
  \blinddocument
}

\end{document}
```