# duodecimal page number

Tags: page-numbering, calculations

I would like to have page numbers in my document written in base 12. Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=1.8in, textheight=0.8in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{$\odot$}
\newcommand{\apple}{$\Delta$}

\begin{document}

The duodecimal numbers:
\begin{center}
1, 2, \ldots, 8, 9, \sirdot,  \apple, 10, 11, \ldots, 19, 1\sirdot,
1\apple, 20, 21, \ldots, \apple 9, \apple\sirdot, \apple\apple, 100 \ldots
\end{center}

\setcounter{page}{10}
Set page counter to 10, so this should be page \sirdot.
\newpage
This should be page \apple.
\newpage
This should be page 10.

\end{document}
```

[image: image of page 10]

Why those particular symbols for 10 and 11? See
http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/sam/duodecimal/ssegm.pdf.

My document is unlikely to need three digit page numbers, which may allow for inelegant hack solutions.

Extra question: `\sirdot` seems to appear just a little too low on the line.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25939/typesetting-babylonian-numerals

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17705/change-the-base-of-the-numeration

Comment: Why did nobody suggest the `dozenal` package on CTAN?

Comment: Error in your PDF: in the multiplication table on page 5, column 2, line sirdot should be 18, not 19 (the whole column 2 must be even numbers!)

Comment: @Zak Thanks. This is just an mwe for the question, so the error doesn't appear anyplace it matters.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With `expl3` it's quite easy (and there's no limit on numbers, other than the usual 2147483647, the maximum number in TeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\basetwelve}{m}
  { \duodec_convert:n { #1 } }

\tl_new:N \l_duodec_string_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \duodec_convert:n #1
  {
   \tl_set:Nx \l_duodec_string_tl { \int_to_base:nn { #1 } { 12 } }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_duodec_string_tl { A } { $\odot$ }
   \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_duodec_string_tl { B } { $\Delta$ }
   \tl_use:N \l_duodec_string_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\basetwelve{\arabic{page}}}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 145 }
  { \basetwelve{#1} ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

The code is in the preamble and after it is a test for showing that the numbers are correctly produced in the requested form.

[image]

The `\int_to_base:nn` function produces `A` for 10 and `B` for 11, so we have to replace the letters with the symbols.

The input `\basetwelve{123456}` produces 5∆540.

---

What do we do? We define a robust command, `\basetwelve`, that will wrap the call to the conversion, performed by `\duodec_convert:n`. This command takes as input something that ultimately expands to a decimal number (for instance `\arabic{page}` and stores away the number converted into duodecimal form, with digits 0123456789AB, through the function `\int_to_base:nn`. Then we replace all A's with `$\odot$` and all B's with `$\Delta$` and deliver the so converted token list.

When LaTeX wants to write a page number to the `.aux` file, it will expand `\thepage`, getting `\basetwelve{\arabic{page}}`. Since `\basetwelve` is robust (all commands defined with `\NewDocumentCommand` are), it will be written untouched. Instead `\arabic{page}` will be expanded to the current page number, so what's written in the `.aux` file is, for instance, `\basetwelve{23}`. When this is used by `\pageref` the conversion will be performed, giving 1∆.

Comment: This is as short as Werner's and more general (though a little harder to read since it relies on some deeper primitives). I'll accept it instead. You say elsewhere that Werner's doesn't work - but it does in my MWE. I'll incorporate his `\smash` and `\raisebox`.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Using a `\label` anywhere in your document would cause problems. `\label` writes to an external `.aux` file, and writes out `\thepage` (in addition to other things).

Comment: @Werner I'm glad I didn't encounter that bug!

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I don't know why. Do I have to use any specific package?

Comment: @PedroG.Mattos Something has changed in the meantime. See the edit.

Comment: It's working now, thanks

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution using the [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) package plus a new `\duodecimal` macro that is modelled  on `fmtcount`'s `\hexadecimal`. (Actually, it's an example of cargo-cult programming: I basically took the `fmtcount` macro set and replaced "hexa" with "duo", "16"  with "12", and "65536" [16^4] with "20736" [12^4].)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=1.8in, textheight=0.8in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\sirdot}{$\odot$}
\newcommand{\apple}{$\Delta$}

\usepackage{fmtcount}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*{\@@duodecimal}[1]{\ifcase#10\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or
6\or7\or8\or9\or $\odot$\or $\Delta$\fi}

\newcommand*{\@duodecimal}[1]{%
\@DT@padzeroestrue
\@DT@loopN=5\relax
\@strctr=\@DT@loopN
\whiledo{\@strctr<\c@padzeroesN}{0\advance\@strctr by 1}%
\@strctr=20736\relax
\@DT@X=#1\relax
\loop
\@DT@modctr=\@DT@X
\divide\@DT@modctr by \@strctr
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@DT@padzeroes}\and\(\@DT@modctr=0\)\and
\(\@DT@loopN>\c@padzeroesN\)}{}{\@@duodecimal\@DT@modctr}%
\ifnum\@DT@modctr=0\else\@DT@padzeroesfalse\fi
\multiply\@DT@modctr by \@strctr
\advance\@DT@X by -\@DT@modctr
\divide\@strctr by 12\relax
\advance\@DT@loopN by -1\relax
\ifnum\@strctr>1
\repeat
\@@duodecimal\@DT@X}

\let\duodecimalnum=\@duodecimal

\providecommand*{\duodecimal}[1]{%
\expandafter\protect\expandafter\@duodecimal{%
\expandafter\the\csname c@#1\endcsname}}

\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\duodecimal{page}}

\begin{document}

The duodecimal numbers:
\begin{center}
1, 2, \ldots, 8, 9, \sirdot,  \apple, 10, 11, \ldots, 19, 1\sirdot,
1\apple, 20, 21, \ldots, \apple 9, \apple\sirdot, \apple\apple, 100 \ldots
\end{center}

\setcounter{page}{10}
Set page counter to 10, so this should be page \sirdot.
\newpage
This should be page \apple.
\newpage
This should be page 10.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Voting your answer up even though I'm accepting  Werner's (less generic, but much simpler and serves my purpose).

Comment: @EthanBolker This answer works. Unfortunately, Werner's doesn't.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a first stab at it and it relies on the fact that you only require two-digit page numbers. As such, this solution is only good up to 144 pages:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=50pt,paperwidth=5em,footskip=-10em]{geometry}%
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newcommand{\basetwelve}[1]{%
  \vphantom{0}\ifcase#1
    0\or1\or2\or3\or4\or5\or6\or7\or8\or9\or\smash{\raisebox{.2ex}{$\odot$}}\or\smash{$\Delta$}%
  \fi%
}
\newcounter{duo}%
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
  \setcounter{duo}{\value{page}}%
  \FPeval\remainder{clip(\theduo-(12*round(\theduo/12-.5:0)))}%
  \FPeval\result{clip(round(\theduo/12-.5:0))}%
  \ifnum\result=0\else\basetwelve\result\fi\basetwelve\remainder%
}
\newcommand{\npage}{\mbox{}\newpage}
\pagestyle{plain}%
\begin{document}
\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage
\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage
\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage
\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage\npage
\end{document}
```

`\basetwelve{<num>}` works like a lookup function, returning 0,1,...,9,"10","11" based on the input values. `\result` contains the first digit of the page number, and `\remainder` the second. [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) was used to perform the modulo calculations for base 12.

Height adjustments for the non-numeric symbols is done using a combination of `\smash` and `\raisebox`, as well as a `\vphantom{0}` for numbers smaller than 12.

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) settings is just for this example.

Comment: Did you try using `\label{a}` somewhere in the document?

Comment: @egreg: No, and I don't want to now that I've seen what it does. How would I fix this? Using an auxiliary macro?

Comment: Sorry, but I wouldn't "fix" this code.

Answer (score 5):

There is alredy a LaTeX2e implematation for a dozenal converter, `\dozens`, provided by the `dozenal` package, which can do the job of @egregs `\basetwelve`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dozenal}
  \renewcommand{\x}{$\odot$}
  \renewcommand{\e}{$\Delta$}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\dozens{\arabic{page}}}

\let\sirdot\x
\let\apple\e

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{10}
Set page counter to $10_{10}$, so this should be page \sirdot.
\newpage
This should be page \apple.
\newpage
This should be page 10.
\end{document}
```

[image: dozenaldemo1]
[image: dozenaldemo2]
[image: dozenaldemo3]