# counter in hexadecimal base

Tags: numbering, counters

I have learned about counters from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393784/how-can-i-sum-two-numbers-in-latex-with-my-own-command).
My question is, can I have a counter in other than 10 base, say hexadecimal one?
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17707/134144 You might also be interested in the `fmtcount` package.

Comment: if this is related to use with \char or \symbol then you do not need hex

Comment: the counter itself does not have a base, the base is just a print form for the value.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK. How do I print hex of a counter? WHich package to use?

Comment: there are several packages,fmtcount is one, but why do you need hex?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % to see more pages
\geometry{paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm,bottom=2cm}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\hexa}{m}
 {
  \egreg_hexa:c { c@#1 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \egreg_hexa:N #1 { \int_to_Hex:n { #1 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_hexa:N { c }
\cs_set_eq:cN { @hexa } \egreg_hexa:N % for \pagenumbering
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\hexa{test}}

\pagenumbering{hexa}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{7}
\setcounter{test}{13}

\stepcounter{test}\thetest
\clearpage

\stepcounter{test}\thetest
\clearpage

\stepcounter{test}\thetest
\clearpage

\stepcounter{test}\thetest
\clearpage

\setcounter{test}{65566}\thetest

\end{document}
```

[image]

More generally, with any base up to 36

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry} % to see more pages
\geometry{paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=5cm,bottom=2cm}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\cbase}{mm}
 {
  \egreg_cbase:nc { #1 } { c@#2 }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \egreg_cbase:nN #1 #2 { \int_to_Base:nn { #2 } { #1 } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_cbase:nN { nc }

\NewDocumentCommand{\newrepresentation}{mm}
 {% #1 = command name, #2 = base
  \cs_new:Npn #1 ##1 { \cbase{#2}{##1} }
  \cs_new:cpn { @\cs_to_str:N #1 } { \egreg_cbase:nN { #2 } }
 }

\newrepresentation{\basexxxvi}{36}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand{\thetest}{\cbase{20}{test}}

\pagenumbering{basexxxvi}


\begin{document}

\raggedright

\setcounter{page}{33}
\setcounter{test}{17}

\stepcounter{test}\thetest, should be~I \\  page~X
\clearpage

\stepcounter{test}\thetest, should be~J \\  page~Y
\clearpage

\stepcounter{test}\thetest, should be~10 \\  page~Z
\clearpage

\stepcounter{test}\thetest, should be~11 \\  page~10
\clearpage

\setcounter{test}{65566}\thetest, should be~83I6 \\  page~11

\end{document}
```

Here `test` is represented in base 20, while the page is represented in base 36. For page numbering, `\newrepresentation` is needed.

[image]

If lowercase letters are preferred, replace `\int_to_Base:nn` with `\int_to_base:nn`.

Comment: How about other base? For example I want my counter display in base 36...

Comment: @Ngiap Added for any base up to 36.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you're after but:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tohex}{m}{\int_to_hex:n {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{43}

\tohex{\themycounter}

\end{document}
```

You could also convert to an arbitrary base (default 16) using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\tobase}{O{16}m}{\int_to_base:nn {#2}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{43}

\tobase[8]{\themycounter}


\end{document}
```